# Phaser: show text when sprites overlap

Tags: phaser-framework

I am trying to work out a way to add a text to the top left corner of the viewport when two of my sprites overlap. One of them is an item and the other is my character. I can already detect for overlap and even "pick" the item (kill the sprite) when I click a key. However I would like that a text saying something like "Click "E" to pick the sword!" appeared while the collision function is active and when I kill the sprite by picking it up the text would vanish.

I tried including the text in the collision function itself but I suppose this way I am rendering the text multiple times (the fps drops a lot) and I just want to create it once and remove it according to my purposes. My code:

```
function collisionHandler(dude,the_sword) {
pickObject.onDown.add(function () {
    the_sword.kill();
}, this);
}

game.physics.isoArcade.overlap(dude, the_sword, collisionHandler, null, this);

// message saying to pick // Where to put this?
var style = { font: "30px Arial", fill: "#ff0044"};
var pick_message = this.game.add.text(0,20,"Click 'E' to pick up the sword!",style);
pick_message.fixedToCamera = true;
```

Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your 'create' function:

```
var style = { font: "30px Arial", fill: "#ff0044"};
var pick_message = this.game.add.text(0,20,"Click 'E' to pick up the sword!",style);
pick_message.fixedToCamera = true;
pick_message.visible = false;
```

Then:

```
function collisionHandler(dude,the_sword) {
pick_message.visible = true;
pickObject.onDown.add(function () {
    the_sword.kill();
    pick_message.visible = false;
}, this);
}

game.physics.isoArcade.overlap(dude, the_sword, collisionHandler, null, this);
```

Something like that should work. If you want to perform other action, like opening the door, you can use:

```
pick_message.setText("Click 'Q' to open the door!");
```

You don't have to create new text evertime, you can use one for different purposes.

Comment: That seems like a good and simple solution. However, now when my character "touches" the other sprite it gets stuck in it and can't move anymore... any ideia why?

Comment: This is a great way of doing it, the only comment I would add is to not have the `onDown.add` within the collision handler. As you're adding an anonymous function in, it'll actually add loads of them (for as long as the sprites remain overlapping). Instead I'd add the `onDown` signal in your `create` function, or have the overlap callback set a flag to let it know it can now be checked, or something along those lines. In short though, the handler will be called potentially hundreds of times, so be careful what's in it :)

Comment: @PhotonStorm I tried setting a variable that changes when the collision handler is activated. I put the on.down on the create function and made an if statement that depends on the value of the variable. Only if it is equal to 1, the onDown can be activated. However I cannot pick the item anymore... Any idea?

Comment: Post a Gist, hard to guess from your description, sorry.

Comment: @PhotonStorm It was a variable problem, nothing serious. Well it works almost perfectly now but when my character activates the function by overlapping it and then he moves away from the object  if he clicks the button he can still pick it up even if not overlapping... How to assure he can only pick up when overlapping?

Comment: The easiest way would be to put a check inside your click function, to test if they are overlapping. If they are, let the function carry on. If not, then bail out. I'm not familiar with the iso plugin, but I expect `overlap` returns a boolean you could use for this check.