# Phaser : collision between sprite and image doesn't work

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

After many fails I can't figure why the collision doesn't work between the player sprite and the totem image. I've re-used the same code from the tutorial in Phaser.io to double check but can't find the issue with both `collide` and `overlap`.

The goal is to unhide the text when the player reaches the totem in this test game : http://likeglue.org/game/

Here's the code:

```js
//Game settings
var game = new Phaser.Game(320, 240, Phaser.AUTO, '', { preload: preload, create: create, update: update });

function preload() {
    //Load game assets
    game.load.image('ground', 'assets/ground.png');
    game.load.image('totem', 'assets/totem.png');
    game.load.spritesheet('player', 'assets/player.png', 18, 18);
    game.load.bitmapFont('carrier_command', 'assets/carrier_command.png', 'assets/carrier_command.xml');

}

var player;
var totem;
var platforms;
var cursors;
var totemSay;
var text;

function create() {
    // scale the game 2x
    game.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.USER_SCALE;  
    game.scale.setUserScale(2, 2);

    // enable crisp rendering
    game.renderer.renderSession.roundPixels = true;  
    Phaser.Canvas.setImageRenderingCrisp(this.game.canvas);

     //  We're going to be using physics, so enable the Arcade Physics system
    game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);

    //  background for our game
    game.stage.backgroundColor = '#000000';

    //  The platforms group contains the ground
    platforms = game.add.group();

    //  We will enable physics for any object that is created in this group
    platforms.enableBody = true;

    //Create ground
    //var ground = platforms.create(0, game.world.height - 32, 'ground');
    var ground = game.add.tileSprite(0, game.world.height - 32, game.world.width, game.world.height, 'ground');

    //Add tileset to group
    platforms.add(ground);
    //  This stops it from falling away when you jump on it
    ground.body.immovable = true;

    //Create totem
    var totem = game.add.image(220, game.world.height - 56, 'totem');
    game.physics.arcade.enable(totem);    

    // The player and its settings
    player = game.add.sprite(32, game.world.height - 50, 'player');

    //  We need to enable physics on the player
    game.physics.arcade.enable(player);

    //  Player physics properties. Give the little guy a slight bounce.
    player.body.bounce.y = 0.2;
    player.body.gravity.y = 500;
    player.body.collideWorldBounds = true;

    //  Our two animations, walking left and right.
    player.animations.add('left', [3, 4], 10, true);
    player.animations.add('right', [1, 2], 10, true);

    //  Our controls.
    cursors = game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

    //Text
    text = "Hello \r\n stranger.";
    totemSay = game.add.bitmapText(-15, -20, 'carrier_command', text, 5);
    totem.addChild(totemSay);
    totemSay.align = 'center';
    totemSay.fixedToCamera = true;
    totemSay.visible = false;
}

function update() {

    //  Collide the player and the stars with the platforms
    game.physics.arcade.collide(player, platforms);

    //Overlapping player with totem
    game.physics.arcade.collide(player, totem, collisionHandler, null, this);


    //  Reset the players velocity (movement)
    player.body.velocity.x = 0;

    if (cursors.left.isDown)
    {
        //  Move to the left
        player.body.velocity.x = -150;

        player.animations.play('left');
    }
    else if (cursors.right.isDown)
    {
        //  Move to the right
        player.body.velocity.x = 150;

        player.animations.play('right');
    }
    else
    {
        //  Stand still
        player.animations.stop();

        player.frame = 0;
    }

    //  Allow the player to jump if they are touching the ground.
    /*if (cursors.up.isDown && player.body.touching.down)
    {
        player.body.velocity.y = -250;
    }*/


}

function collisionHandler (player, totem) {

    // Totem talk
    totemSay.visible = true;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title> PyPlatformer </title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="phaser.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

The closest topic to my issue here was on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39336100/phaser-show-text-when-overlap-sprites), somehow it didn't work :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing

`var totem = game.add.image(220, game.world.height - 56, 'totem');`

use

`totem = game.add.image(220, game.world.height - 56, 'totem');`

When you write the keyword `var`, it creates a local variable which is only accessible to the `create` method. Removing the `var` keyword will make it accessible everywhere.

If it still does not work then maybe you will have to convert your totem into a `sprite` object and enable physics for that object. I am new to phaser and I'm not sure whether images have physics bodies which would allow them to perform physics operations.

Comment: Hi B.Naeem, thanks a lot for your help, actually removing 'var' and changing 'game.add.image' by 'game.add.sprite' make the difference, I can't believe I've been knocking my head for that long on such small details ;) cheers !

Comment: No problem buddy. Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `var platforms` line while declaring.

And overlapping function is `game.physics.arcade.overlap(....)`

Hope it helped.

Comment: Hi Neeraj, I've tried earlier with both 'collide' and 'overlap' to trigger the text but none worked as I mentioned. Removing 'var platforms' didn't do anything unfortunately.